# Angular Material: Components background color became transparent after customizing theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

#### Issue:

After customizing the theme colors of my Angular Material application, multiple material components lost their background colors such as (MatTooltip, MatSelect, MatDialog etc...)

I followed the [Official Guide](https://v11.material.angular.io/guide/theming) to customize the theme of my app, and I'm pretty sure I followed everything to the letter, but then this weird bug happened and no suggestion on the internet helped with it.

#### Screenshots:

- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjZ63.png) of `MatTooltip` losing the backgroundColor.
- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUwHS.png) of `MatSelect` losing the backgroundColor.

#### The theme file `_theming.scss`:

This is the file used for theming the app, I created two themes, light and dark, switchable by class.

```css
@import 'node_modules/@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$light-primary     : mat-palette($mat-blue, 800);
$light-accent      : mat-palette($mat-amber, 500);
$light-warn        : mat-palette($mat-red, 500);
$light-theme       : mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $light-primary,
    accent: $light-accent,
    warn: $light-warn,
  )
));

$dark-primary      : mat-palette($mat-blue, 800);
$dark-accent       : mat-palette($mat-amber, 800);
$dark-warn         : mat-palette($mat-red, 800);
$dark-theme        : mat-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $dark-primary,
    accent: $dark-accent,
    warn: $dark-warn,
  )
));

.light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($light-theme);
}

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}
```

This file is imported in the global `styles.scss`. No other theme is imported.

#### Version info:

- Angular Version: 11
- Angular Material Version: 11

Comment: You will have to use `::ng-deep` on the right selector for that. Inspect your element, try to find which selector reflects the desired `background-color` on the developer tools (*i.e. `.mat-tooltip`*) and then it would go somwthing like `::ng-deep .mat-tooltip { background-color: red; }`.

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Yes I could go deep with the customization of the background color , but I want to understand why is this happening in the first place, and why isn't this mentioned in the official guide

Comment: Are all material components losing their `background-color` attribute or only some of them?

Comment: Could you please inspect the `MatSelect` and confirm that `.mat-select-panel` `background`'s value corresponds to the colors you set?

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly I found out that the styling is completely missing, like this one for MatTooltip: `.mat-tooltip {
  background: rgba(97,97,97,.9);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround, not pretty but effective:

1- Copy the content of a prebuilt theme (choose a light or dark theme as you wish) from the path `node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/` into a new scss file.

2- Prepend your color variables to the top of the file

```scss
$color-primary : // choose your color
$color-accent  : // choose your color
$color-warn    : // choose your color

// Default theme below
// ...
```

3- Using a text editor find and replace the default theme colors with the respective variable:

```scss
/* 
* If deeppurple-amber theme:
*    - Replace #673ab7 with $color-primary.
*    - Replace #ffd740 with $color-accent.
*    - Replace #f44336 with $color-warn.
* ==================================================
* If indigo-pink theme:
*    - Replace #3f51b5 with $color-primary.
*    - Replace #ff4081 with $color-accent.
*    - Replace #f44336 with $color-warn.
* ==================================================
* If pink-bluegrey theme:
*    - Replace #c2185b with $color-primary.
*    - Replace #b0bec5 with $color-accent.
*    - Replace #f44336 with $color-warn.
* ==================================================
* If purple-green theme:
*    - Replace #7b1fa2 with $color-primary.
*    - Replace #69f0ae with $color-accent.
*    - Replace #f44336 with $color-warn.
* ==================================================
*/
```

4- Compile and change your theme dynamically by referencing the theme

```html
<head>
  ...
  <link id="theme" rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
```

```ts
this.document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href', this.chosenThemePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

These components have their own styling. Either overwrite them with your own values or unset them:

In template:

```html
<mat-paginator class="background" ... >
</mat-paginator>
```

Stylesheet:

```css
.background {
  background-color: unset;
}
```

Since this is happening in multiple places in your app and you seem to want to implement a dark-theme, you could also add a class in your styles.scss:

```css
.theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-light);
}

.dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme-dark);
}
```

And add them conditionaly on a boolean:

```html
[ngClass]="{ 'dark-theme': isDarkTheme }"
```

or:

```html
[ngClass]="{ isDarkTheme? 'dark-theme' : 'theme' }"
```

Comment: I tried this approach but nothing changed unfortunately. I Didn't really get what you mean by unsetting the background-color, since this property seems to be missing in the first place after applying the theme, so there is nothing to unset.

Comment: I added some more options. If you can make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) I'm willing to take a look at your code.

Comment: Thank your for offering help, I already created a [StackBlitz Project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bfwgw?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) for that using the exact configuration I have in my project

Comment: This end with error: './src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Undefined mixin.
   ╷
30 │   @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
   │   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
'

ALWAYS test your answers.